# Get all items starting with a given string

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I want to get all items which start with a given string.
The code below returns thousands of items when I do **not** use the predicate, but when it is present I get zero records returned.
I have tested with field names and terms which for sure exist in the sqlite db.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context        = [[DataSource sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription    *entityDesc     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSSortDescriptor       *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES];
NSPredicate            *predicate      = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ beginswith %@)", fieldName, searchTerm, nil];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entityDesc];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];

return objects;
```

**Solved**
The following solved the problem:

```
NSString               *str            = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ beginswith \"%@\"", fieldName, titleTerm];
NSPredicate            *predicate      = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];
```

The content was having wrong quotation wrappings.

Answer (score 1):

When solving your own problem you should answer your own question rather than editing the question. If you don't this question will show up as unanswered. You can go ahead and accept this answer and the question will be properly marked as solved.

---

The following solved the problem:

```
NSString               *str            = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ beginswith \"%@\"", fieldName, titleTerm];
NSPredicate            *predicate      = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];
```

The content was having wrong quotation wrappings.